# getting img src within a link

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble with retrieving the src of an image that is part of a link. For example with this I would like to retrieve the src of the img between the  tag. 
`<a href="/video1234/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1234.jpg" id="pic_1234" /></a>` 
I will need to do this for a couple of the links on the page that are all laid out the same. So what I tried so far is this:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;

    @$dom->loadHTML($html);

    $i = 0;
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    //Get images
foreach ($links as $link){
    $test = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (strpos($test,'/video') !== false) { 
        $XV_IMG[$i] = $link->nodeValue;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

If the link does not contain an img tag only, but instead it has plain text it will work just fine. Is there any way to get the src?

Comment: How would you want to `retrieve the src of the img between the tag`? Send it out in an alert or what?

Comment: just storing the src which in the example would be http://example.com/picture1234.jpg in the array $XV_IMG[$i]

Comment: `src` is an attribute.  Just do what you did with `href` to fetch it.

Comment: theres alot more images on the site I only need to retrieve the sources of the pictures from within those links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep using getElementsByTagName on the node like this

```
foreach ($link->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
  $XV_IMG[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use preg_match_all

```
$html=  '<a href="/video1234/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1234.jpg" id="pic_1234" /></a>
<a href="/video1224/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1224.jpg" id="pic_1224" /></a>
<a href="/video1434/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1434.jpg" id="pic_1434" /></a>
<a href="/video1554/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1554.jpg" id="pic_1554" /></a>
<a href="/video1334/the_vid"><img src="http://example.com/picture1334.jpg" id="pic_1334" /></a>';

preg_match_all('/<a href="(.*)"><img src="(.*)" id="pic_[0-9]{1,7}" \/><\/a>/i',$html,$out);
unset($out[0]);
unset($out[1]);
print_r($out);
```